# References and context through functions and classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just to say first that I'm new to python and that I use python version 3.6.5
I'm not really confortable with the way python is handling function input as "object references".

The examples given here are really simple just to show my point.

This is the first code that I'm running (wrong behaviour):

```
integer = 0

def func(t): return integer

class FooClass(object):
    def __init__(self, input_function):
        self.function = input_function

    def give_value(self, index):
        print(self.function(index))

foo_object = FooClass(func)

foo_object.give_value(0)
# Output >> 0

integer = 1

foo_object.give_value(0)
# Output >> 1
```

I want my FooClass object to be totally independant of external changes.

This is the second code that I'm running (right behaviour):

```
integer = 0

def step_function(integer_input):   
    def func(t): return integer_input

    return FooClass(func)

class FooClass(object):
    def __init__(self, input_function):
        self.function = input_function

    def give_value(self, index):
        print(self.function(index))

foo_object = step_function(integer)

foo_object.give_value(0)
# Output >> 0

integer = 1

foo_object.give_value(0)
# Output >> 0
```

I'm happy with it, but I don't understand why it works. Actually, I'm afraid that my self.function is refering to the 'integer_input' defined during the step_function call. So that it is refering to an available space of memory that can be overriden (if that makes any sense in python).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's extremely hard for me to comprehend your code because all variable names are meaningless letters (edit: some of which you *reuse*!). Also, could you come up with a shorter example that shows the same behavior that irritates you? In the meantime, I have a hunch that [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) will help you in any case.

Comment: @timgeb Ok thanks, I will edit the question to make it easier to understand. I will come back after watching the video.

Comment: If you're coming from another language it can be hard to get used to Python's data model. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. For a shorter and slightly different take on this topic see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to explain why your codes function differently: `integer` is a name that refers to an integer. In your first example, you are using this name in `func` and this creates a closure that wraps up a reference to `integer` from the *global* scope and passes it along. Thus, all future calls reference whatever is held by the name `integer` in the global scope.

In your second example, you create the new name `integer_input` to reference `integer` and reference `integer_input` in `func`. This creates a closure that wraps up a reference to `integer_input` from the *function* scope and passes it along.

If you were somehow able to change what `integer_input` referenced in your `step_function` scope, you would run into the same issue, but this would be difficult to do (and practically impossible to do unintentionally).

If you want to update your first example to work as you expect it to, you could use the following instead:

```
func = (lambda value: lambda t: value)(integer)
```

This manually creates a closure to decouple the *name* `integer` from the *object* referenced by `integer` and is akin to your second example.

Or, to update your current structure to do something similar:

```
def step_function(integer_input):   
    def inner(t): return integer_input
    return inner

func = step_function(integer)
```

Note that these two approaches are equivalent, only the syntax is different.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the code with a more simple example, so I don't know if I should undo the edit or if you can adapt your answer to the new code. If I understand your answer, the bar variable stay in the function scope, but that scope still exist after the foo call?

Comment: Your answer is really understandable thanks! I know it's not the cleanest way, but there are many things over this code and for the moment it was the easiest and fastest way to do it for me. But I will check for nicer ways!

Comment: @LA.Dufrene Yes, a scope still exists after `return FooClass(func)` because `FooClass` stores a reference to `func` and `func` needs to know the value of `integer_input`, so this is wrapped up in a closure.

Comment: Thanks for your new answer. I clearly understand what happens now!